# MFC: How do I construct a good regular expression that validates URLs?

Tags: regex, mfc, visual-c++

Here's the regular expression I use, and I parse it using CAtlRegExp of MFC :

(((h|H?)(t|T?)(t|T?)(p|P?)(s|S?))://)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9])

It works fine except with one flaw. When URL is preceded by characters, it still accepts it as a URL.

ex inputs:

- this is a link www.google.com (where I can just tokenize the spaces and validate each word)
- is...www.google.com (this string still matches the RegEx above :( )

Please help... 
Thanks...

Comment: Note that `(h|H?)(t|T?)(t|T?)(p|P?)(s|S?)` matches strings like: `ht`, `htp`, `tt`, etc.

Comment: 1) you are missing non-http protocols (like ftp: or mailto:); 2) you are not going to match non-default port URLs (ie, something like http://example.org:8000); 3) you are missing urls with user identity; 4) the regex above will work only with English or IDN ruls; but it will barf on any url-encoded url or url with unicode entities in it.

In other words, you are going to match only a very small subset of valid urls.

Comment: more url goodness the regex above is not covering - 5) less or more than three parts in the host name (ie www.example.org.uk); 6) location fragment or query parameters; 7) resource paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the regex to only match at the start and end of the string.  I'm not sure how you do that in VC++ - in most regexs you enclose the pattern with `^` and `$`.  The `^` says "the start of the string" and the `$` says "the end of the string."

```
^(((h|H?)(t|T?)(t|T?)(p|P?)(s|S?))\://)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9])$
```

The second is matching because the string still **contains** a valid URL.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the IgnoreCase flag instead of catering for each case.
2. Stick a `^` at the beginning if you want the start of the string to be the start of the URL
3. You're missing a **lot** of characters from possible, valid URLs.

Answer (score 2):

How about using CUrl (that is, 'C-Url', in ATL, not curl as in libcurl) which can 'parse' urls with CUrl::CrackUrl . If that function returns FALSE you assume it's not a valid URL.

That said, decomposing URL is sufficiently complex to warrant a proper parser, not a regex based decomposition. Cfr. rfc 2396 etc. for an overview on the complexities.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one: `(((f|ht)tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+) ?`

Comment: `{1}` is just noise: it can be left out.

Comment: With `\+`, are you escaping the `+`, or trying to include the literal backslash? If it's the first, the `+` needs no escaping inside a character class and if it's the latter, it needs an extra backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Start the regex with `^` to and end it with `$` to have the regex match only if the entire sting matches (if that's what you want):

```
^(((h|H?)(t|T?)(t|T?)(p|P?)(s|S?))\://)?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9])$
```

Answer (score 1):

This Regular Expression has been tested to work for the following

http|https://host[:port]/[?][parameter=value]*

```
public static final String URL_PATTERN = "(https?|ftp)://(www\\.)?(((([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.){1,}[a-zA-Z]{2,4}|localhost))|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}(\\d{1,3})))(:(\\d+))?(/([a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:@/]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?(\\?([a-zA-Z0-9-._~!$&'()*+,;=:/?@]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?(#([a-zA-Z0-9._-]|%[0-9A-F]{2})*)?";
```

PS. It also validates on localhost link.

(Thoroughly written by me :-))